# Can't upload CSV file to plugin directory using custom upload form in admin panel

Tags: php, plugin-development, uploads, csv

I need some assistance here. So far, i build a plugin, that are able to import data of a CSV file and parse it into fields of a custom post type.

At this point, I would like to make a form to display in admin panel, from were the admin can upload a new CSV file from.

The custom form i have build is displayed below.

```
// Check whether the button has been pressed AND also check the nonce
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

            echo '<p>File upload button was clicked!</p>';
            // the button has been pressed AND we've passed the security check
            file_upload_action();
        }

        echo '<form action="?page=csv-data-importer-slug" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';

            echo '<p>Upload a File:</p>';

            echo '<input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileToUpload">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="submit">';
            submit_button('Upload File Now');
        echo ' </form>';
```

The following function is handling the file upload. Within the function i included some error handling. See below:

```
function file_upload_action() {

    $enableimport = true; 

    echo "<p>File upload function is now running!</p>";

    $currentDir = getcwd();
    $uploadDirectory = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "uploads/";

    echo $uploadDirectory;

    $errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here

    $fileExtensions = ['csv']; // Get all the file extensions

    $fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));

    $uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

    var_dump($fileTmpName);
    var_dump($uploadPath);

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {
            $errors[] = '<p>This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a CSV file</p>';
        }

        if ($fileSize > 2000000) {
            $errors[] = '<p>This file is more than 2MB. Sorry, it has to be less than or equal to 2MB</p>';
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

            if ($didUpload) {
                echo '<p>The file ' . basename($fileName) . ' has been uploaded</p>';


            } else {
                echo '<p>An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the admin</p>';
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo $error . '<p>These are the errors' . '\n' . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($didUpload);

    return;
}
```

The error handling when executing is outputting following lines:

- File upload button was clicked!
- File upload function is now running!
- C:\Users\kim_a\Desktopserver\www.fiske-makker.dev.cc\wp-content\plugins\fiske-makker-data-importer/uploads/
- C:\Users\kim_a\Desktopserver\www.fiske-makker.dev.cc\wp-content\plugins\fiske-makker-data-importer\data-importer.php:164:string 'C:\xampplite\tmp\phpDA2F.tmp' (length=28)
- C:\Users\kim_a\Desktopserver\www.fiske-makker.dev.cc\wp-content\plugins\fiske-makker-data-importer\data-importer.php:165:string 'C:\Users\kim_a\Desktopserver\www.fiske-makker.dev.cc\wp-adminC:\Users\kim_a\Desktopserver\www.fiske-makker.dev.cc\wp-content\plugins\fiske-makker-data-importer/uploads/fredningszoner-kort.csv' (length=191)
- An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the admin
- C:\Users\kim_a\Desktopserver\www.fiske-makker.dev.cc\wp-content\plugins\fiske-makker-data-importer\data-importer.php:194:boolean false

So the function keeps resulting in the boolean "$didUpload" being false, which indicates, that the files was not upload.

I need some suggestions to areas i could troubleshoot within this function or some code review, if someone see an error, that i missed myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the reason you upload a file to the plugin directory. The standard way to upload a file is to the WordPress `uploads` directory.

In your code, I find this one is wrong

```
$uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName);
```

See, you merge two path together. Try

```
$uploadPath = $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName);
```

But again, it is not the correct way, you should upload files to `wp_upload_dir()` instead.

Comment: Duh ! You are completely right. The path was merged. Problem solved!